# Occasional firewall spikes on ports in 40000 - 60000 range over VPN

Tags: port

I am hoping someone will recognise the description below and be able to tell me what they think might be going on..

I look after an office network,  which has VPN access to a different network located at a hosting center.   Most of the computers on both networks are Windows Machines (W7, W2K8r2, W2K3)

There is a roughly steady flow across this VPN of about 8mbps.   But roughly every 4-8 hours we see a massive spike between the two networks.  the bandwidth speed spikes to somewhere between 100 and 400mbps and the amount of data transfered in this spike is between 8 and 9gb.

We have PRTG network monitoring running at the hosting center end.  During the last spike I was able to see that the spikes were on what appear to be dynamic ports in the range 40000 - 60000. For these particular transfers PRTG is only showing the firewall ips so we are not able to isolate the problem to specific machines on either end. I realize this is not much to go on but can anyone recognize this pattern as something they've seen before and might know the cause?

[image]

**Edit (11/02/2014):**  I have since discovered that the source ports are also random, but the protocol is something called **ESP** (I will google but at the moment I'm not sure what it is)

[image]

Comment: This isn't terribly helpful, but you could always do the "block and wait for a phone call"... And see if your users isolate it for you. Or only allow the ports you know they need over the VPN.

Comment: @MikeAWood It's a nice idea but unfortunately the stuff we're operating is business critical.   I have since discovered that the data is using 'ESP' protocol and the source ports are random as well as dest.  Ports were already restricted on the VPN so these things might be establishing themselves over an allowed port such as 443.

Comment: Are the source and end points your appliances?  could this just be the VPN traffic showing up as ESP?  Could be something as simple as Backup, RSync, WSUS, DFS-R, etc schedule causing the burst in traffic perhaps?  If the traffic seems to be all internal, I'd look for something scheduled that might be causing it.